# How can I install costmap_converter_msgs (ROS2)?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do not know how to install costmap_converter_msgs of ROS2

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343469/how-can-i-install-costmap_converter_msgs-(ros2)?/) by [lorenzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/51527/lorenzo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2020-02-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That package has been [released recently](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/23617) so is not available in the main repository. It will be on the next package sync (happens ~ every month).

In the meantime you can either:

install it from the testing repository:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64,arm64] http://packages.ros.org/ros2-testing/ubuntu `lsb_release -cs` main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-testing.list'
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ros-eloquent-costmap-converter-msgs
```

Or build it from source:

```
mkdir -p ~/costmap_converter_ws/src && cd ~/costmap_converter_ws/src
git clone https://github.com/rst-tu-dortmund/costmap_converter -b ros2
cd ~/costmap_converter_ws/
colcon build --packages-select costmap_converter_msgs
```

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2020-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lorenzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/51527/lorenzo/) on 2020-02-07**:
Thank you so much for the answer!

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2020-02-07**:
Glad it solved your problem. Can you please mark the answer as accepted (by clicking the checkmark) ? this way the question will be marked as resolved